# Kde applications menu not working in ubuntu 18.04 after upgrade

Tags: drop-down-menu, kde-plasma, ubuntu-18.04

I cannot display the drop-doown-menus of any KDE applications like kile, okular texmaker. However, I can click on the menus, but it does not show all the elements that it should show. 
ubuntu 18.04.1 (gnome3) LTS

Any hint is appreciated!

Solved: There was a problem with the display that I do not know why prevented to correctly display the menus. So I turned off one of the 3 monitor in the setting displays menu and then it worked! Thanks cadash!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, I would try setting colors, window style and window decoration to defaults.
Since you mention it happenned during a system upgrade, also try doing:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

If it installs anything, reboot and give it a try. 
If none of this works and you can backup your personal info, doing a fresh install might be the best option as you might encounter additional issues caused by the upgrade in the future.

Comment: Thanks, but the system was fresh installed and everything was working until this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I just re read your question, I thought you were using KDE but now I see you are using Ubuntu and native QT/KDE applications are looking bad. Try looking for some graphical setting that allows you to change the style or color for KDE/QT applications.

I dont use gnome or ubuntu so I wouldn't know exactly where to find it but I think GNOME had an option to change QT settings. If you can't see anything like that you should look for available qt packages related to gnome, I would do something like that:

```
apt-cache search qt | grep gnome
```

You should even be able to install some new QT styles like Oxygen for your apps